# What happened to Luke's hand in The Last Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, luke-skywalker

At the end of Star Wars The Last Jedi, Luke

> became a Force Ghost and vanish lefting only his clothes.

But what happens with his bionic hand?

> It dissapear with him? It was counted as part of Luke's organic body?

Comment: Just to note though that the only thing of Luke's left was his cloak, all the other clothes he was wearing disappeared with him, same as Obi wan.

Comment: Vader was "more machine than man" but his Force Ghost still looked mostly intact at the end of ROTJ (even in the original pre-Hayden Christiensen edit.)  Either the robotic limbs go with them or (more likely IMHO) the original "organic" limbs are "restored" upon transition.  (Not really organic though, because they're ghosts now.)